# Cocos2d issue with ios5

Tags: iphone, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to compile an old code that was working.

```
PlayView *layer = [[[PlayView alloc] initWithColor:ccc4(180, 180, 200, 255)] autorelease];
```

I'm getting this error:

> Cannot Convert 'ccCoor4b' to 'ci' color in argument passing.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: PlayView is a CCLayerColor? this code should work i dont get errors

Comment: Could you post here declarations of `PlayView::initWithColor:` and `ccc4(...)`?

Answer (score 2):

change the code to:

```
return [[(CCLayerColor*)[self alloc] initWithColor:color] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work !

```
PlayView *layer = [[[PlayView alloc] initWithColor:(ccColor4B){180, 180, 200, 255}] autorelease];
```

You can try this way also,

```
ccColor4B c;
c.r=180,c.g=180,c.b=200,c.a=255; 
//then use 'c' as ccColor4B object
```